# Switching language with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I want to add another language to my website (an app written in PHP 7).
I found out, good SEO practices say that every page on my site should be accessible from differend URLs, depending on the language.

Currently my .htaccess looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9-]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So when user types in (or clicks a link) http://example.com/contact they get page contact.php (if exists). 
What I want to achieve is, to redirect http://example.com/en/contact to the very same file contact.php, but with $_GET argument **and still redirecting /contact to contact.php** (without this argument). I thought that would be:

```
... everything from above code sample and then:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-z0-9-]+)$ $1.php?lang=en [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas why and how to make this work?

Comment: Use the QSA flag? `[QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: are you using an MVC pattern? Do you have a routing component?

Comment: What happens if you actually type `/contact.php?lang=en` into the address bar? Is that working as expected?

Comment: Yes, /contact.php?lang=en is working like expected. I just want to redirect /en/contact to this address, so I don't have to pass GET arguments in every link on my site

Comment: ... and to make it look better than ?lang=en

Comment: I think it's getting tied in knots when it reroutes `$1.php` try removing the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` conditions ... I *think* they're superfluous anyway.

Comment: One thing, I just noticed you have `a-zA-z` where you are using a capital A and little z. Shouldn't affect things but just in case... Also, try changing your code to this `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last condition checks that `en/file.php` exists, which is never the case. That's why the rule is never met. Either you remove it (but it will be applied even on nonexistent files) or you use this workaround by rewriting the faulty condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^en/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?lang=en [NC,L]
```

To be more complete, you can also redirect users that try to access `/contact.php?lang=en` directly (better for SEO). Here is how your final htaccess should look like

```
RewriteEngine On

# if url is /file.php?lang=en and file exists then redirect to /en/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/\s\?&]+)\.php\?lang=en\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/%1? [R=301,L]

# if url is /en/file and /file.php exists then internally rewrite to /file.php?lang=en
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^en/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?lang=en [NC,L]
```

Note: the above code is specific to `en` language, but you can easily adapt it to multiple languages